# nginx reverse proxy and ports

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I had a question regarding a proxy pass.  A lot of tutorials show a configuration like this in some way or form, with a port identifed:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass        http://x.x.x.100:80;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the port needs to be used?  Does it need to be a specific number, or is it even necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explicityly specified port is:

- not necessary IF you're reverse proxying to something on the default http (80) or https (443) ports
- necessary if you're reverse proxying to something running on any non-default port (common when your application server and webserver are on the same host)

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass shows examples shows examples without the portnumber